# Equation Array Exceed Right Margin

Tags: equations, margins, eqnarray

I write equations in `eqnarray`use Latex, but there are lines that exceed the right margin, how to fix it?

This is my code:

```
\begin{eqnarray}    
    k_1&=&hf(t_i, y_i)=hf_i \label{$k_1$ RK-4}\\
    k_2&=&hf(t_i+p_1h, y_i+q_11_k1)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}k_1f_y)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)\\    
    k_3&=&hf(t_i+p_2h,y_i+q_21k_1+q_22k_2)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_2hf_t+q_21k_1f_y+q_22k_2f_y)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22} h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)f_y)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}hf_if_y +q_22h^2p_1f_tf_y+q_{11}q{22}h^2f_i(f_y)^2)\\
    k_4&=&hf(t_i+p_3h, y_i+q_31k_1+q_32k_2+q_33k_3)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}k_1f_y+q_{32}k_2f_y+q_{33}k_3f_y)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}hf_if_y+q_{32} h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)f_y +q_{33}h(f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}hf_if_y+q_{22}h^2p_1f_tf_y+q_{21}q_{22}h^2f_i(f_y)^2)f_y)\nonumber\\
       &=&h(f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}hf_if_y+q_{32}hf_if_y +p_1q_{32}h^2f_tf_y +q_{11}q_{32}h^2f_i(f_y)^2+q_{33}hf_if_y+p_2q_{33}h^2f_tf_y+q_{21}q_{33}h^2f_i(f_y)^2+q_{22}q_{33}h^2f_i(f_y)^2+q_{22}q_{33}p_1h^3f_t(f_y)^2+q_{11}q_{22}q_{33}h^3f_i(f_y)^3)\\
\end{eqnarray}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: The equation is too wide because it is too wide. However, you already know how to introduce line breaks. Please note that most users have switched to `align` instead of `eqnarray`. (However, the latter does not solve the problem automatically, `breqn` does in principle but I personally would rather break the lines by hand than using `breqn`.)

Comment: @liswyhy Just to remind you that the `>`s in your code block prevent your code from being compilable. Removing that is better. (and I did it for you.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the standard advice of not using `eqnarray` for whatsoever reason, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196), I'd recommend using `split` for this, so to divide each block into a single unit.

With the `tbtags` option, we ensure that the number attached to a `split` equation is added at the bottom (when equation numbers are on the right) or at the top.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath} % for math

\begin{document}
\begin{align}    
k_1 &= hf(t_i, y_i)=hf_i \label{k1_RK_4}
\\
\begin{split}
k_2 &= hf(t_i+p_1h, y_i+q_{11}k_1) \\
    &= h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}k_1f_y) \\
    &= h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
k_3 &= hf(t_i+p_2h, y_i+q_{21}k_1+q_{22}k_2) \\
    &= h(f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}k_1f_y+q_{22}k_2f_y) \\
    &= h[f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)f_y] \\    
    &= h[f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}hf_if_y+q_{22}h^2p_1f_tf_y+
       q_{11}q_{22}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2]
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
k_4 &= hf(t_i+p_3h, y_i+q_{31}k_1+q_{32}k_2+q_{33}k_3) \\
    &= h(f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}k_1f_y+q_{32}k_2f_y+q_{33}k_3f_y) \\
    &= h\{f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}hf_if_y+q_{32}h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)f_y \\
    &\qquad +q_{33}h[f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}hf_if_y+q_{22}h^2p_1f_tf_y \\
    &\qquad +q_{21}q_{22}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2]f_y\} \\
    &= h\{f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}hf_if_y+q_{32}hf_if_y+p_1q_{32}h^2\!f_tf_y+
       q_{11}q_{32}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2 \\
    &\qquad +q_{33}hf_if_y+p_2q_{33}h^2\!f_tf_y+q_{21}q_{33}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2+
     q_{22}q_{33}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2 \\
    &\qquad+q_{22}q_{33}p_1h^3\!f_t(f_y)^2+q_{11}q_{22}q_{33}h^3\!f_i(f_y)^3\}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can `multline` be another solution? P.S. Nice answer!

Comment: +1. You may want to point out explicitly the role that setting the option `tbtags` plays here. :-)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to inserting some line breaks by hand in the final two rows, you also need to fix some of the notation by adding curly braces as needed in the terms `q_11`, `q_21`, `q_22`, etc. (And `_k1` should be `k_1`, right?) When the parenthetic structures are nested, it helps readers if square brackets and curly braces are used in addition to round parentheses, to help detect the orders of the parentheses.

And you most definitely should *not* be using the badly deprecated `eqnarray` environment. Use the `align` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package, instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment and '\notag' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{align}    
    k_1 &= hf(t_i, y_i)=hf_i \label{k1_RK_4}\\
    k_2 &= hf(t_i+p_1h, y_i+q_{11}k_1) \notag\\
     &= h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}k_1f_y) \notag\\
     &= h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)\\   
    k_3 &= hf(t_i+p_2h, y_i+q_{21}k_1+q_{22}k_2)  \notag\\
     &= h(f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}k_1f_y+q_{22}k_2f_y) \notag\\
     &= h[f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)f_y] \notag\\    
     &= h[f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}hf_if_y+q_{22}h^2p_1f_tf_y+q_{11}q_{22}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2]\\
    k_4 &= hf(t_i+p_3h, y_i+q_{31}k_1+q_{32}k_2+q_{33}k_3) \notag\\
     &= h(f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}k_1f_y+q_{32}k_2f_y+q_{33}k_3f_y) \notag\\
     &= h\{f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}hf_if_y+q_{32}h(f_i+p_1hf_t+q_{11}hf_if_y)f_y \notag\\
     &\qquad +q_{33}h[f_i+p_2hf_t+q_{21}hf_if_y+q_{22}hf_if_y+q_{22}h^2p_1f_tf_y \notag\\
     &\qquad +q_{21}q_{22}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2]f_y\} \notag\\   
     &= h\{f_i+p_3hf_t+q_{31}hf_if_y+q_{32}hf_if_y+p_1q_{32}h^2\!f_tf_y+q_{11}q_{32}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2 \notag\\
     &\qquad +q_{33}hf_if_y+p_2q_{33}h^2\!f_tf_y+q_{21}q_{33}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2+q_{22}q_{33}h^2\!f_i(f_y)^2 \notag\\
     &\qquad+q_{22}q_{33}p_1h^3\!f_t(f_y)^2+q_{11}q_{22}q_{33}h^3\!f_i(f_y)^3\}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention another adjustment I made: I inserted negative thinspace (`\!`) in all instances of either `h^2` or `h^3` being followed by `f`. This avoids creating "visual holes" in the formulas.